# How can I publish messages from pc to android phone (android_tutorial_pubsub)

Tags: android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have modified the android_tutorial_pubsub using the Lorenz's patch ([http://ias.in.tum.de/~moesenle/android_tutorial_pubsub.patch](http://ias.in.tum.de/%7Emoesenle/android_tutorial_pubsub.patch)). I connect the pc and phone to the same router and set the masterURI to the ip of the pc which is http://192.168.0.2:11311/. Then I start to see the familiar "Hello world! n". On pc, I can see the android node and the talker using $rosnode list, like: 
/android_gingerbread/ros_text_view
/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/talker
/rosout.
However, in the rxgraph mode, the 3 nodes are not connected to each other. Why?
Then, I tried to publish a message using 
$rostopic pub /chatter std_msgs/String -r 1 "abc".
But the Textview in the phone didn't show any message like "abc" but still "Hello world!n". The rxgraph show the 4 nodes separately (not connected to each other).
I got really confused. Can anybody help me on this? I am new to the Rosjava, and any help will really be appreciated. Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31391/how-can-i-publish-messages-from-pc-to-android-phone-(android_tutorial_pubsub)/) by [alexbeta20](https://answers.ros.org/users/2130/alexbeta20/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2012-04-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alexbeta20](https://answers.ros.org/users/2130/alexbeta20/) on 2012-04-06**:
when I tick on the ALL Topics option on the rxgraph. The 4 nodes are connected correctly. But the Text view is still not showing the "abc". This is really difficult to understand for me. Anyone can help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably just need to define ROS_IP in the environment you're running the publisher:

```
$> export ROS_IP=192.168.0.2
```

Without it set I saw a similar behavior, and things weren't connected.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1